# Does $lcm\{1,2,...,n\} = \prod_{p\leq n, p\in\mathbb{P}}p^{\lceil \frac{log(n)}{log(p)}\rceil}$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I am trying to understand Apery's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ from start to end, with [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Echaubey2/snehathesis.pdf) document. I apologise for having 2 questions in one, but both are relatively simple (I just need to be sure I completely understand each part of the proof).

It says in the preliminaries that $$lcm\{1,2,...,n\} = \prod_{p\leq n, p\in\mathbb{P}}p^{\lceil \frac{log(n)}{log(p)}\rceil}$$ and gives the following proof:[image: Supposed proof of lemma.]

But it seems to have a mistake - when it says $\lceil x \rceil$ is the highest integer power of $p$ such that it's smaller than $n$, as surely $p^{\lceil x\rceil}\geq n$?

Following this and relatedly, it says that [image: Second lemma]

Why is this true? I'm satisfied that it proves the second statement, but why are the lemma and the proved statement equivalent?

Comment: For the first, if it *is* the ceiling function, then I think that it is a mistake. For the second, it seems that the equality in Lemma 3.1.2. does not hold for $n=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the ceiling function with the floor function. Let $N=lcm(1,\dots,n)$. If $p$ is a prime and $k$ and integer bigger or equal than $1$, then you have:

1) if $p^k\le n$, then $p^k|N$ by definition of $N$;

2) if $p^k|N$, then there must be an integer $1\le  m\le n$ such that $p^k|m$, by definition of $lcm$ (and prime numbers). Therefore $p^k\le n$.

It follows that for any prime $p$, $p^k|N$ if and only if $p^k\le n$, which is equivalent to $k\le \lfloor \log_p n \rfloor$. Therefore the exponent of the power of $p$ in the prime factorization of $N$ is $\lfloor \log_p n \rfloor$ as claimed.

Comment: I thought so (I meant to mention that this was what I believed they meant). The rest of the above proof works if you assume they meant the floor.